# Alexander polynomials for Pretzel knots

Tags: curated-data, knots

All knots, such as this torus knot,

```
KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {3, 5}}]
```

[image: Torus knot]

have an associated Alexander polynomial:

```
KnotData[{"TorusKnot", {3, 5}}, "AlexanderPolynomial"][x]
```

$$x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}-x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}+x+\frac{1}{x}-1 .$$

Why aren't the Alexander polynomials for a pretzel knot, such as this,

[image: Pretzel knot]

available?

```
KnotData[{"PretzelKnot", {5, 4, 3}}, "AlexanderPolynomial"]

Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

Comment: I guess that the properties in `KnotData` are not computed on the fly but that they are tabulated. I am not sure; maybe the [``"KnotTheory`"``](http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Mathematica_Package_KnotTheory%60) package can help you further.

Comment: Supporting Henrik's supposition, comparing `Length@KnotData[{"PretzelKnot", {5, 4, 3}}, "Properties"]` (i.e., `67`) with `Length@DeleteCases[KnotData[{"PretzelKnot", {5, 4, 3}}, #]& /@ KnotData[{"PretzelKnot", {5, 4, 3}}, "Properties"], Missing["NotAvailable"]]` (i.e., `15`), you see that most of the knot properties are not available for this particular knot.